# Find all points in DB which are in the radius of a lat and long

Tags: c#, .net, distance

I have in DB SQL Server saved point in 2 fields- lat and long

I get point, and I want find all the points from my DB in radius of five minutes walking distance.

What's the best way to do it?

I read that there is a way to do it with GeoDanjo. But I understand that it doesn't work with SQL Server.

There also ways to do it if you save the data in geography type but it is not relevant either.

Comment: I don't know if it is the best method, but, if you ignore the curvature of the earth (which for 5 minutes walk is imprecise enough to be irrelevant), you can use Pythagoras.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT your-fields WHERE sqrt ( ( lat - lat1 )^2 + ( long - long1 )^2 ) < your-distance;
```

Where lat1 and long1 are your reference point values.

Very rough approximation for short distances (as someone noted in the comments).

Comment: In which type should we write the distance?

Comment: Sorry, I oversimplified... You'll need to convert the angles to distances. The principle using an SQL query is the same though.

Comment: http://www.m0nwk.co.uk/software-tools/how-to-calculate-distance-between-two-points-using-latitude-and-longitude/

Comment: I think MySQL has a geo-spacial datatype and proximity lookup by radius, which would be exactly what you want. It might be worth looking into how that is implemented in MySQL, because the above method feels very brute-forcey to me, and is likely to be processing-heavy.

Comment: For the sake of performance, you might want to do this operation on a cte which has already selected where abs(lat - lat1) < your_distance and abs(long - long1) < your_distance. This would avoid performing an expensive operation ( square root on the sum of two squares) for all records in the database.